# PostgreSQL: How to use REPLACE with dynamic replacement text

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to generate the string, `download_url`, for each row of the `dataset` table using `REPLACE` with a simple template string. The `id` of each row should be substituted into the template string.

Here's what I've tried below. Given that `id` in the subquery is correlated with the outer query, I thought that this would work:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       REPLACE('https://example.com/dataset/{id}/download/', '{id}', id) 
as download_url
FROM dataset;
```

but I am getting an error indicating no function exists:

> [42883] ERROR: function replace(unknown, unknown, integer) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have read the error message and hint properly!

The solution was to cast `id` as a string like so:

```sql
SELECT id,
       name,
       REPLACE('https://example.com/dataset/{id}/download/', '{id}', id::varchar) as download_url
FROM dataset;
```